# How do I mock this on C++?

Tags: c++, googlemock

```
FuncRes Test::test(HttpRequest& request, std::string& result) {
    try {
        auto httpClientSync = HttpClientSync::create(param);
        HttpResponse response = httpClientSync->execute(request);
        if (...) {
            return FuncRes::SUCCESS;
        } else if (...) {
            return FuncRes::RETRY;
        } else {
            return FuncRes::FAILED;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        return FuncRes::RETRY;
    } catch (...) {
        return FuncRes::FAILED;
    }
}
```

httpClientSync is a local variable, it will destroy when the test is done.
I'm confused if I can mock HttpClientSync and "execute" method?

Comment: In order to mock `httpClientSync` it needs to be a parameter of some kind.  The least invasive way of doing this that I can see is having the type `HttpClientSync` be a default template value and then template on the mock's type when you need to.

Comment: I could not get yout point, could explain it more detail?  Thanks.
//     EXPECT_CALL(*getHttpClientSyncMock(), execute(_))
//         .Times(testing::AtLeast(1))
//         .WillRepeatedly(Throw(XXX("ConnectionTimeout")));

Comment: Can't you mock `HttpRequest request` such that all types of `HttpResponse response` are obtained when calling `httpClientSync->execute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor this function into 2 parts, one that creates real HttpClientSync, and one that accepts HttpClientSync interface:

```
FuncRes Test::test(HttpClientSync& httpClientSync, HttpRequest& request, std::string& result);

FuncRes Test::test(HttpRequest& request, std::string& result) {
  auto httpClientSync = HttpClientSync::create(param);
  test(httpClientSync, request, result);
}
```

Then test variant which accepts HttpClientSync in arguments, and pass mock instead of real client.

If you need to test some *other* code which calls this `test` function, and you still want to mock HttpClientSync, then instead of storing `param` in your Test class, store `HttpClientSync& client` instance, and pass it in constructor.